# Оптимизация drag&drop

Tags: c#, wpf, оптимизация, drag-n-drop

В общем у меня есть программа на которой лежит два `rectangle`, когда зажимаем(`mouse_down`) первый `rectangle` то фиксируем координаты мышки, при перемещении(`mouse_move`) обновляем координаты `rectangle` и начинаем при помощи `FindVisualChildren<Rectangle>(childUI)` и `FillContainsWithDetail` циклически проверять что есть пересечение, если пересечение отлавливает то у второго (на который накладывается) `Rectangle` меняем цвет, а если отпускаем на пересечении, то накладываем первый `rectangle` на второй и меняем у первого цвет.

Так вот, если у меня 200 будет rectangle'ов то программа адцки виснет из-за моего цикла, подскажите как можно было бы всё это оптимизировать?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вам вызывать `FindVisualChildren` на каждой итерации? Мне кажется, достаточно

1. Иметь и поддерживать в актуальном состоянии список всех rectangle'ов
2. При перемещении элемента проверять пересечение с каждым по списку.

При таком подходе `FindVisualChildren` не нужно.

Comment: Думаете быстрее будет?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Куда оно денется? :) Разве что вы где-то в другом месте не делаете что-то ещё медленное.

Comment: хорошо вечером проверю 